# Android market showing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting following exception on android market for my app.

```
Exception class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Source method WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked()
```

I am unable to understand why and where this is coming from? I never got this exception on my device. Does anybody have a clue how to solve this? Or see it on my device?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:355)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:200)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeView(Window.java:432)
at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:278)
at android.app.Dialog.access$000(Dialog.java:71)
at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:111)
at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:268)
at android.app.Dialog.cancel(Dialog.java:951)
at com.bappy.cror.GameActivity$17$1.run(GameActivity.java:719)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you also include the source for `GameActivity.java`. Specifically, I'd like to see what `line 719` corresponds to.